# Can we send body to any route like http post request with payload?

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have a scenario, I want to hit a route i-e /app/access and with body and i want to access that body like

`activeRoute.getBody()` in ngOninit.

can we do exactly like this? or any other way to send post params to route and access by active route ?

Answer (score 0):

No we can't. Because every route is HTTP Get and we can't send body / payload to HTTP GET request.

we can't convert the route of angular to POST from GET because this is default behavior of request.

simple we can said that we can't send HTTP Post request to any route or convert any route to HTTP POST route.

If we want to achieve, we have wrap the application to some server side language like Scala and Java or induct any middle wear servlet.